# Is there a way to put a breakpoint or listen to any confirm box in Developer tool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way for Developer tool to put a breakpoint or listen to an event whenever any confirm box is triggered?

This is asked with the assumption that we have no idea where the confirm box is located and we want to trace its origin.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "Event Listeners" in Chrome Developer Tools:

[image: Screen shot of Dev tools "Event Listener" location]

The "confirm" box could have a click event attached to it.

Alternatively you can use Firefox to identify the location of the JS event in their dev tools here:
[image: Firefox JS Event location]

Comment: The closest option I can find in my chrome Developer tool's event listener was Mouse > Click, and it didn't put a breakpoint to the confirm box. Is there something else I missed out?

Comment: I'm assuming you can see the "confirm" box in a browser, but you don't know where the js exists in your code / repo right?

if that is the cause consider using Firefox, inspect the element and it'll show you its associated "events", from there you can find the JS file in your "sources" panel, and break point on your local browser. I've updated my answer with an additional screen shot for you.